# Show that: $\varphi$ maps $\alpha$ to a $\beta_i$ and $\varphi (\alpha)=\varphi^´(\alpha)\rightarrow \varphi = \varphi^´$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> Let $\varphi:K \rightarrow L$ be a homomorphism of fields and $N/K$ be a finite field extension. The continuation is definded as $\phi:N \rightarrow L$. Let $\alpha\in N$ and $f$ the minimal polynom of $\alpha$ over $K$. Now consider the zero points $\beta_1,...,\beta_k$ of $f$ in $L$ and show that:
>
> - $\varphi$ maps $\alpha$ to a $\beta_i$
> - $\varphi (\alpha)=\varphi^´(\alpha)\rightarrow \varphi = \varphi^´$

Unfortunately another exercise from an old algebra exam which I'm really struggling to solve. Maybe someone could give me a hint? Thanks in advance!

Further information:

- Definition of a continuation:

A continuation of a function is a another function. The domain of the other function includes a subset which is equal to the original function.
So the official definition is:

Let $X, Y$ and $A$ sets. A function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is called a continuation of the function $g: A \rightarrow Y$, if $A$ is a Subset of $X$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in A$.

- Definition of a finite field extension

$(N/K)$ is a finite field extension of the fields $N$ and $K$

A field extension is a pair of fields $K \subseteq N$, such that the operations of $K$ are those of $N$ restricted to $K$. In this case, $N$ is an extension field of $K$ and $K$ is a subfield of $N$. For example the complex numbers are an extension field of the real numbers and the real numbers are a subfield of the complex numbers.

If written like above $N/K$ then $K$ is a subfield  of $N$ and $N$ is the extension field/extension of $K$. Finite meaning there are a finite amounts of elements

**Edit:** $N$ is given by $N=K(\alpha)$. For the first task you need to set and $f(\alpha)=0$, but I am unsure how to procced.

Comment: The result of this exercise immediately implies the result of your other question about the number of extension homomorphisms; do you see it?  Because there are only $n$ of your $\alpha$'s.  Use this result + algebraicity of any finite extension on your other problem.

I think you will immediately see why the first part is true on your own if you clean up your question a little bit.  $f$ is defined with coefficients from $K$, so when you talk about the polynomial $f$ "over $L$" that's actually a bit sloppy, isn't it?  Drop the slop and it becomes trivial by def of field (ring) homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi: K \to L$ be a fixed field morphism, let $n =$ deg$(f)$ and let $\phi(f)$ be the corresponding polynomial in $L[x]$. If $\psi: N \to L$ is a field morphism that extends $\phi$, then $\psi(\alpha)$ is a root of $\phi(f)$ since if
$$ 0 \: = \: f(\alpha) \: = \: a_{n}\alpha^{n} \: + \: ... \: + \: a_{1}\alpha \: +  \: a_{0} $$
then an application of $\psi$ shows that
$$ \psi(0) \: = \: 0 \: = \: \phi(a_{n}) \cdot \psi(\alpha)^{n} \: + \: ... \: + \: \phi(a_{1}) \cdot \psi(\alpha) \: +  \: \phi(a_{0}) \: = \: \phi(f)(\psi(\alpha)) $$
because $\psi$ is a field morphism that equals $\phi$ on $K$ (and therefore on  the coefficients of $f$).

Next, since $N = k(\alpha)$ and $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$, the sequence $(\alpha_{i})_{i = 0}^{n - 1}$ forms a linear basis for $N$ over $K$. In other words, each element $b$ of $N$ may be written as $b_{n}\alpha^{0} + ... + b_{n}\alpha^{n}$ for coefficients $b_{i}$ in $K$. After applying $\psi$, we get
$$ \psi(b) \: = \: \phi(b_{0}) \cdot \psi(\alpha)^{0} \: + \: ... \: + \: \phi(a_{n}) \cdot \psi(\alpha)^{n} $$
Hence every field morphism extension of $\phi$ to $N$ is completely determined by where it maps $\alpha$.